# How do I get a result from this specific API request?

Tags: javascript, api, discord.js

I am currently trying to make a command in my discord bot that will track your stats in Rainbow six Siege. I am using an API for this, but I can't get any results out of my API request. The API gives a player ID between "players" and "profile", but I have no idea how to get around it. I also tried to get the response via an array, but that also gave no results. The thing I want to achieve is getting the player name for example, but I don't know how to get a value out of there. I thought r.body.players.profile.p_name, but that doesn't work because the API gives a player ID in between it. Maybe that someone knows how to work around it?

[The result of r.body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD900.png)

[The code I want to use to simply get the player name, but "profile" will be undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afXSS.png)

[This is what the API responds when just pasting the link in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWQZm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`Object.entries(...)`

`Object.entries` requires an object to send and 
it returns new array with key and value.

For eg:

```
let data={
    "4cc06f42-86f6-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003": {
       name: "Stack Overflow",
       type: "website"
    }
}
let newArr=Object.entries(data);
/*["4cc06f42-86f6-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003",{name: 
     "Stack Overflow",
     type: "website"}]*/
```

You can access the key by:

```
let key=newArr.map(value=>value[0])
// ["4cc06f42-86f6-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003"]
```

You can also use array destructing

```
let key=newArr.map(([key,value])=>key)
// ["4cc06f42-86f6-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003"]
```

Comment: could you explain how I would use that in my own code? I totally don't have a lot of experience with coding. I made my own simple discord bot and wanted to make a simple stat tracker for my bot, but it turns out that it isn't so simple for me.

Comment: give me the sample code, will modify and send to you

Comment: `client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    const name = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
    if(message.content.includes(`${prefix}r6`))
    snekfetch.get("https://r6.apitab.com/search/uplay/" + name + "?u=1585761495&cid=4420eaff-662a-40ff-9e9c-36da5551e2e4").then(r =>{
        const content = r.body.players.profile.p_name;
        message.channel.send(content);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
});`
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/NyckYsJ)

Comment: fetch(
  "https://r6.apitab.com/search/uplay/stack?u=1585761495&cid=4420eaff-662a-40ff-9e9c-36da5551e2e4"
)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    `console.log(data);
    let players = data.players;
    let playersID = Object.entries(players).map(([key, value]) => key); //returns an array of players id

    console.log(players[playersID[0]]);
    //displays the first player details. you can use forloop to iterate`
  });